# Spring data - A different object with the same identifier even if the objects are equals

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a project built with spring boot 2.2.6 and I am trying to insert/update an entry(*Parent*) in a database and cascade de operation to its children, if a child doesn’t exist it should be inserted otherwise it should be updated. I have the following classes:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    List<Child> children1;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    List<Child> children2;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"id"})
public class Child {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

```
public interface ParentRepository extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> {
}
```

```
@Service
public class TestService {

    private ParentRepository parentRepository;

    public TestService(ParentRepository parentRepository) {
        this.parentRepository = parentRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void save() {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Child c1 = new Child(1L, "c1");
        Child c2 = new Child(1L, "c1");
        List<Child> children1 = new ArrayList<>();
        children1.add(c1);
        List<Child> children2 = new ArrayList<>();
        children1.add(c2);

        parent.setChildren1(children1);
        parent.setChildren2(children2);

        parentRepository.save(parent);
    }
}
```

I don’t have any other configuration and with this I receive the following error:

`A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [Child#1]`

I don’t understand why I am receiving this error because c1.equals(c2) is evaluated to true.

If I change the type of children1 and children2 to Set, I am receiving the following error:

`Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.CHILD(ID) [1, 'c1']"`

Now I don’t understand why I am receiving this error because I am expecting the merge cascade type to handle this issue, to make updates instead of inserts.

Can you help me understand what am I missing out? Can you give me some tips on what is the best practice to insert/update objects in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

Although the objects equal in Java, it doesn't mean they are the same entity in the persistence context. Once you do:

```
Child c1 = new Child(1L, "c1");
Child c2 = new Child(1L, "c1");
```

... and persist them using the `PERSIST` cascade, both objects are about to be persisted and since their IDs are equal, the unique ID constraint is violated. The solution is to use the same object, therefore the entity will be created only once:

```
Child c = new Child(1L, "c1");

List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
children.add(c);

parent.setChildren1(children);
parent.setChildren2(children);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I need two relationships children1 and children2 that may have the same objects, what would be a solution if these would be two lists of Child?

Comment: Still the same. Let's say, there is a `Parent` with `id=1` and a `Child` with `id=1` persisted in the database. The `@ManyToMany` relationship is held by a new table representing `children1` and `children2` relationships. The table has `id, parent_id, child_id` and the first two rows will look like `1, 1, 1` and `2, 1, 1`. So there will be 2 different relationships pointing to the same entity. If you want to achieve the 2nd child entity is different, then it needs to have a different ID.

Comment: Can you give me some documentation to read? I didn't understand very well how can I fix my issue

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_entity_relationships.htm help to understand `@ManyToMany` and the persisted state of an entity by example. Here is a comprehensive documentation  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html